# add a video youtube playlist use youtube data api v3

Tags: java, android, insert, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using playlistItems insert i have this code

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=MyKey&access_token=access_token

```
{
 "snippet": {
  "playlistId": "WL",
  "resourceId": {
   "videoId": "qcKXO58Rh-o",
   "kind": "youtube#video"
  }
 }
}
```

but i can't run on my java code what can i do it for runnig this.

Comment: Use Http get method to get json data in android  and parse this data and show this list.

Comment: Are you have an example i couldn't this.

Comment: Search internet via "Android JSON Parsing Tutorial". Please search google every before ask any here.